# Error message in Django when I try to runserver - does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you s ee valid patterns in the

Tags: python, django

Every time I write `python manage.py run server`. I get the error message:

```
The included URLconf '<module 'strana.views' from 'D:\\novi projekat\\strana\\views.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

mysite **urls.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('strana/', include('strana.views')),
    ]
```

**myapp**(named strana)

```py
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**views.py**

```py
    from django.http import HttpResponse


    def index(request):
        return HttpResponse('Kita u Bila')
```

Answer (score 2):

You included your views module. You want to include the module that contains your urls.

```
from django.contrib import admin from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('strana/', include('strana.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Thank you Mr genius. This solved the problem, was learning from documentation and got a little confused... finally can continue now